# Loading resources from multiple jars with wild card

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have a Java application with multiple modules, each module has a `jar` file.
each jar file follows same folder structure called `META-INF/props`Is there a way in java to load all the property files which are in `META-INF/props of multiple jars using a wild card?

Something like

`ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("META-INF/props/*.properties");`

I know that this method does not accept wild cards and does not return array of streams , but is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Not really.  You can use [`ClassLoader#findResources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#findResources(java.lang.String)), which will return an `Enumeration` of all resources named the same within the class path, but this still expects a fully qualified path and name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard/reliable way to do this. Some libraries take advantage of common patterns of ClassLoader.getResources implementations (specifically, that they usually always return "file:" or "jar:file:" URLs) in order to support wildcards in resource lookups.  For example, the [Wildcards in application context constructor resource paths](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-app-ctx-wildcards-in-resource-paths) explains how Spring does this, and it lists several caveats ("Implications on portability", "Classpath*: portability", "notes relating to wildcards").

Comment: Yeah I know that spring supports wild card loading, that is the reason I asked the question, I thought Java has in built mechanism to scan classpath.

Comment: The answer is that it does not. If you're willing to make assumptions about the environment, you can emulate.

Comment: @Puru I filed an issue with Spring to separate out their resource loading into a lightweight artifact: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12508 Please vote it up if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code to get around this this limitation.

I read all entries from class path and determine if it is a folder or a JAR file and then look for the entries in "META_INF/props". If the entry is a property, I load it.

Below is the code, it is not refined but it gives general idea.

```
try{
    URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) LoaderTest.class.getClassLoader()).getURLs();
    HashMap<String, Properties> mapProperties = new HashMap<String, Properties>();

    for(URL url: urls){
        File file = new File(url.getFile());
        if(file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("Directory: " +file.getName());
            File propFolder = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/META-INF/props");
            if (propFolder.exists() && propFolder.isDirectory()){
                for(File f: propFolder.listFiles()){
                    if(f.getName().endsWith("properties") || f.getName().endsWith("props")){
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        props.load(new FileReader(f));
                        String appName = props.getProperty("load.global.props.appName");
                        if(appName != null){
                            if( mapProperties.get(appName) == null) {
                                mapProperties.put(appName, props);
                            } else {
                                mapProperties.get(appName).putAll(props);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (file.getName().endsWith("jar")){
            System.out.println("Jar File: " + file.getName());
            JarFile jarFile = null; 
            try{
                jarFile = new JarFile(file);
                Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
                while ( entries.hasMoreElements() ){
                    JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                    if ( entry.getName().startsWith("META-INF/props") && 
                            (entry.getName().endsWith("properties") ||
                            entry.getName().endsWith("props"))){
                        System.out.println("Prop File: " + entry.getName());
                        Properties props = new Properties();
                        props.load(jarFile.getInputStream(entry));
                        String appName = props.getProperty("load.global.props.appName");
                        if(appName != null){
                            if( mapProperties.get(appName) == null) {
                                mapProperties.put(appName, props);
                            } else {
                                mapProperties.get(appName).putAll(props);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                if ( jarFile != null ) jarFile.close();
            }
        }
    }

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```